# Já existe um DataReader aberto associado a este comando que deve ser fechado primeiro?

Tags: c#, combobox

Tenho um `combobox` que está recebendo dados de uma tabela do meu BD MySql. Até ai tudo bem.

Entretanto, quando retorno pra tela inicial, onde este se encontra, ele acaba dando um problema (Já existe um `DataReader` aberto associado a este comando que deve ser fechado primeiro).

Já procurei e já fiz o que resolveu o problema de terceiros (criar uma segunda conexão), mas não funcionou muito bem. Segue código do método:

```
 public DataTable GetUF()
 {

        DataTable dataUf = new DataTable();
        MySqlConnection bdConn = new MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;server=localhost;database=controle;uid=root;pwd=''");
        try
        {
            bdConn.Open();
            if (bdConn2.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                //Se estiver aberta faz a consulta dos dados do BD
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT identificador FROM computador WHERE status=0", bdConn);
                cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
                dataUf.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Impossível estabelecer conexão.\n" + ex.Message);
        }

        return dataUf;

}
```

Código do ComboBox que está recebendo os dados:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cbComputador.ValueMember = "identificador";
        cbComputador.DisplayMember = "identificador";
        cbComputador.DataSource = GetUF();
    }
```

***Observação:*** achei este `link`, mas não me ajudou muito:

> [Já existe um DataReader aberto associado a este comando que deve ser fechado primeiro.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/147d9d22-dfbd-4c66-a20b-137780addc07/j-existe-um-datareader-aberto-associado-a-este-comando-que-deve-ser-fechado-primeiro?forum=vscsharppt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faltou chamar o método [`Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) e fechar a **conexão com o banco**, realmente  todas as vezes que utilizar um [`IDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.idatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) precisa fechar logo após seu uso e dar o comando [`Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) para liberar recursos.

```
public DataTable GetUF()
{
    DataTable dataUf = new DataTable();
    MySqlConnection bdConn 
        = new MySqlConnection(
        "Persist Security Info=False;server=localhost;database=controle;uid=root;pwd=''");
    try
    {
        bdConn.Open();
        if (bdConn2.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
                           "SELECT identificador FROM computador WHERE status=0", bdConn);
            dataUf.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        bdConn.Close();
        bdConn.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Impossível estabelecer conexão.\n" + ex.Message);
    }
    return dataUf;
}
```

---

<sub>**Observação:**</sub>

No [SQL Server](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) 2005 e versões superiores, existe uma forma de configurar a conexão para trabalhar com vários [IDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.idatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) abertos, que é configurar o recurso [MARS - Multiple Active Result Sets](http://www.macoratti.net/13/05/adn_mcc1.htm) da seguinte forma: na `string` de ***conexão*** adicione a configuração:

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

***Exemplo:***

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" + 
             "Initial Catalog=Banco;Integrated Security=True;" + 
             "MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
```

<sub>**Referencias**</sub>

- [IDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.idatareader(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Interface IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Microsoft SQLServer](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)
- [Habilitando vários conjuntos de resultados ativos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Manipulating Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yf1a7f4f.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Parece que resolveu meu problema. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Se foi útil @DLopes aceite como resposta!